# Firebase application cannot access pages other than the index

Tags: firebase, ember.js

I'm writing my own blog site in EmberJS and will be deployed via firebase

I have a very simple application with 3 routes.

This is the welcome page

[image: Welcome]

It's URL is

```
https://foo.firebaseapp.com/welcome
```

This is the blog page

[image: Blog here]

It's URL is

```
https://foo.firebaseapp.com/blog
```

Lastly I have a login page (not shown), and an index (which only redirects to \welcome).

So here's the problem: If I go to

```
https://foo.firebaseapp.com
```

Then it will redirect to the welcome page as expected. Furthermore, it displays `https://foo.firebaseapp.com/welcome` in my browser URL. However, if I go to

```
https://foo.firebaseapp.com/welcome
```

It does NOT go to the webpage. Instead it returns:

[image: not found]

What this means is that I can't access individual routes/pages in my application. In order to get to /login, /welcome, or /posts, I have to get there from the index.

Why is firebase behaving this way? How can I access urls without going to the index first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to configure your firebase project as a single-page app. That will configure your firebase.json to redirect all URLs to index.html

Comment: That is correct. I needed it to be a single-page app. That fixed it. I just had to do firebase init.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I've been deploying my applications by calling `firebase init` in the command line.

At some point, they ask

> Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?

And I was answering no to this. But since I'm using ember (which IS a single page app), I needed to say yes to this step.